# How i can mutiple events in addEventListener ? (without jq)

Tags: javascript

i want to write in the console Hello world ! everytime i click  the button **or** i press on enter

this is my code :

```
// important vars 
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const input = document.getElementById('input').value;
const todoUl = document.createElement("ul");
const todoLi = document.createElement("li")
const todoList = document.getElementById('todolist'); // this the div that contain ul and li

// this function is for add input value and create list's 
const addTodo = function(){
    
    console.log('hello world!')

    
};

// later ..
btn.addEventListener('click' , addTodo);
btn.addEventListener('submit' , addTodo)
```

Comment: `input.addEventListener('keyup', function(ev){if (ev.keyCode == 13){addTodo()}})` this will call `addTodo` when you hit enter when tipying on input

Comment: The `Submit` event should handle both `click` and `enter`.